# Switch from top/left positioning to transition equivalent without layout jank

Tags: html, css

I have a div that is positioned using top and left properties. And I need to dynamically switch the positioning from top/left to its transform equivalent. The problem is that when I apply `top: 0`, `left: 0` and equivalent transform property, the div jumps to 0,0 for a split second, before positioning correctly. I understand that changing top and left properties triggers layout redraw.

Here is a example of this behaviour: [codepen](https://codepen.io/julijanjug/pen/qBYELqm).
When applying Animation1 for the first time the described problem occurs, but it then works as expected after that.

```html
<div class="red gpu" style="left: 120px; top: 100px;"></div>
<div class="border original">120,100</div>
<div class="border moved">270,180</div>
<button onclick="animate1()">Animate1</button>
<button onclick="animate2()">Animate2</button>
```

```js
function animate1() {
  let div = document.querySelector('div');
  div.style.cssText = `
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    transform: translate(120px, 100px) translate(150px, 80px);`;
}
function animate2() {
  let div = document.querySelector('div');
  div.style.left = `0px`;
  div.style.top = `0px`;
  div.style.transform = `translate(120px, 100px)`;
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transition: transform 2s;
  position: absolute;
}
.border {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: fixed;
}
.original {
  left: 120px;
  top: 100px;
}
.moved {
  left: 270px;
  top: 180px;
}
```

Is there a way to prevent this from happening? I tried applying top/left and transform properties in separate requestAnimationFrames and using translate3d without any luck.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Is there a specific reason not to animate the `top` and `left` properties directly?

Comment: @Baro Without getting into too much detail, yes, there are limitations that prevent me from just using `transform` from the start.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set in the `css` what the starting state is and then change only the `transform` property.

```js
function animate1() {
  let div = document.querySelector('div');
  div.style.transform = `translate(120px, 100px) translate(150px, 80px)`;
}
function animate2() {
  let div = document.querySelector('div');
  div.style.transform = `translate(120px, 100px)`;
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transition: transform 2s;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px; top: 0px; 
  transform: translate(120px, 100px);
}
.border {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: fixed;
}
.original {
  left: 120px;
  top: 100px;
}
.moved {
  left: 270px;
  top: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div class="red gpu"></div>
<div class="border original">120,100</div>
<div class="border moved">270,180</div>
<button onclick="animate1()">Animate1</button>
<button onclick="animate2()">Animate2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not animating `top` and `left` so it's changing them abruptly. You could try `transition: all 2s;` so that it applies to anything, or `transition: top 2s, left 2s, transform 2s;` to specify only the properties you are using.

NOTE: [Animating non-transform properties can have a negative impact on browser performance](https://web.dev/animations-and-performance/) so do that with caution, if you can set the original position with just the transform (with top/left 0) you would be better off and your original code would probably work as expected.